# How to parse a string into a datetime object with Django

Tags: python, django

So I have a string like this:

```
2012-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

Hopw can I transform it into an object I can save in my model, which has this field:

```
start_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just need to parse this string into a datetime object.

Answers are here:
[How to parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-iso-formatted-date-in-python)

so you can use `dateutil.parser` or `iso8601` modules.